# Best way to download depth data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a Three.js application that needs to download some depth data. The data consist of 512x256 depth entries, stored in a compressed binary format with the precision of two bytes each. The data must be readable from the CPU, so I cannot store the data in a texture. Floating point textures is not supported on many browsers anyway, such as Safari on iOS.

I have this working in Unity, but I am not sure how to go about downloading compressed depth like this using javascript / three.js. I am new to javascript, but seems it has limited support for binary data handling and compression.

I was thinking of switching to a textformat, but then memory footprint and download size is a concern. The user could potentially have to load hundreds of these depth buffers.

Is there a better way to download a readable depth buffer?

Comment: What makes you think JavaScript doesn't handle binary data well? First off there are fetch and typedarrays. Second every browser has built in gzip and broti compression so you can serve compressed files and they'll magically appear uncompressed in the browser. There are also tons of JavaScript decompression libraries. [Here's one](https://greggman.github.io/unzipit). Also what does this have to do with three.js? Nothing in your question says anything about three.js

Comment: @gman What's up with all the negativity? As I said, I am new to Javascript. Three.js is an API that, among other things, has some built in loaders that might have a solution, that's why I mentioned it so that people who know the API might know of a way to load binary data from it. I heard Typed Arrays doesnt work on all browsers, but if it does, I still dont know how to download binary data. I don't have detailed access to the server setup, and cannot set up compressed transfers there. The data has to be precompressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a file as binary data with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```js
async function doIt() {
  const response = await fetch('https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/eye-icon.png');
  const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();

  // the data is now in arrayBuffer
}
doIt();
```

After that you can make [TypedArray views](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) to view the data.

```js
async function doIt() {
  const response = await fetch('https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/eye-icon.png');
  const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
  console.log('num bytes:', arrayBuffer.byteLength);
  
  // arrayBuffer is now the binary data. To access it make one or more views
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  
  console.log('first 4 bytes:', bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
  
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  console.log('bytes 1-3 as unicode:', decoder.decode(bytes.slice(1, 4)));
}

doIt();
```

As for a format for depth data that's really up to you. Assuming your format was just 16bit values representing ranges of depths from min to max

```
uint32 width
uint32 height
float min
float max
uint16 data[width * height]
```

Then after you've loaded the data you can use either muliplte array views.

```
const uint32s = new Uint32Array(arrayBuffer);
const floats = new Float32Array(arrayBuffer, 8); // skip first 8 bytes
const uint16s = new Uint16Array(arrayBuffer, 16); // skip first 16 bytes

const width = uint32s[0];
const height = uint32s[1];
const min = floats[0];
const max = floats[1];
const range = max - min;

const depthData = new Float32Array(width * height);
for (let i = 0; i < uint16s.length; ++i) {
  depthData[i] = uint16s[i] / 0xFFFF * range + min;
}
```

If you care about endianness for some future world where there are any browsers running on big endian hardware, then you either write your own functions to read bytes and generate those values or you can use a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView).

Assuming you know the data is in little endian format

```
const data = new DataView(arrayBuffer);

const width = data.getUint32(0, true);
const height = data.getUint32(4, true);
const min = data.getFloat32(8, true);
const max = data.getFloat32(12, true);
const range = max - min;

const depthData = new Float32Array(width * height);
for (let i = 0; i < uint16s.length; ++i) {
  depthData[i] = data.getUint16(i * 2 + 16, true) / 0xFFFF * range + min;
}
```

Of you want more complex compression like a inflate/deflate file you'll need [a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uzip-module) or to write your own.